# "Remain a cool kid" vs. "remain as a cool kid"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

Which of the following is grammatical?

> - He wants to remain a cool kid for the rest of his life.
> - He wants to remain as a cool kid for the rest of his life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Remain a cool kid" is preferred in American English. I've seen "Remain as" used in Commonwealth English, although I don't know whether it's considered more acceptable than "remain" alone.

Comment: And `stay` is better than `remain`.

Comment: @Malvolio Would you explain why?

Comment: `Remain` has the connotation of involuntariness, of things "left over".  Consider *Remains of the Day*, "remainder" (in division), "human remains".  `Stay`, besides being the less formal word, has the connotation of *deliberateness*, of *will*, of "I meant to do that".  Consider "mainstay" (on a ship, the line holding the mast upright; metaphorically, the chief support of anything) or expressions like "stay strong"  and "stay safe".  Bureaucratic instructions might say "remain standing" but in an emergency, people yell "stay there" or "stay away".